# Post only one controller to do this mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Good day ..
I am using `@Html.action` to list the users of Acitve directory, the Post when it happens it passes through two controller, the controller for New User, and the controller that makes the list of User, you have some way to make the post
only happens in the controller New User?
I tried using `@Html.BeginForm ("New", "Users"))`
but had no success .. if you have any way to solve it .. ?

This my code and the new user

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Novo(NovoViewModel novoViewModel)
    {



        //Validações de autenticação
        if (_authenticationService.IsUserRegistered(novoViewModel.NomeUsuario))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ExistingUsername", String.Format(ViewModelValidations.ExistingUsername, "Usuário"));
        }

        if (_usuarioRepository.ObtemPorEmail(novoViewModel.Email) != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ExistingEmail", String.Format(ViewModelValidations.ExistingEmail, "Email"));
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            IList<Perfil> perfisSelecionados = new List<Perfil>();
            novoViewModel.PerfisSelecionados.ToList().Select(x => _perfilRepository.ObterPorId(x)).ToList().
                ForEach(perfisSelecionados.Add);

            Usuario usuario = new Usuario()
                                  {
                                      Nome = novoViewModel.Nome,
                                      Email = novoViewModel.Email,
                                      Telefone = novoViewModel.Telefone,
                                      DataNascimento = Convert.ToDateTime(novoViewModel.DataNascimento),
                                      Sexo =
                                          !String.IsNullOrEmpty(novoViewModel.SexoSelecionado)
                                              ? (Sexo?)(Convert.ToByte(novoViewModel.SexoSelecionado))
                                              : null,
                                      Credencial = new Credencial()
                                                       {
                                                           NomeUsuario = novoViewModel.NomeUsuario,

                                                           Status =
                                                               (Status)
                                                               Convert.ToByte(novoViewModel.StatusSelecionado),
                                                           Perfis = perfisSelecionados
                                                       }
                                  };

            _usuarioRepository.Adicionar(usuario);

            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        novoViewModel.Sexos = GetSexos();
        novoViewModel.Status = GetStatus();
        novoViewModel.Perfis = GetPerfis();

        return View(novoViewModel);


    }
```

Comment: Show us the code for new user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.BeginForm("New", "Users"))` will post to the action New in the Users controller. if you want to post to NewUser controller you should have this instead:

```
@Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "NewUsers"))
```

Comment: did not work .. happens when the post is still going through the controller that makes the list of all
  of the users .. happening in the action seeking a User by the name ... an example
except when a New User and lack algun required field adds to the model error and the model Retron with error messages at this time there is the post in the method of seeking a
User not being sent to look .. and this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the code

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   ......
   ......

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This means, when POST passes through NewUser action, and information is valid, it redirects to  index action (`RedirectToAction("Index")`). When browser receives redirect command, it **silently, automatically issues all new, fresh request** to Index action. And this second, silent and automatic request may cause you think that POST to NewUser passes through Index action as well. In fact, it does not. It is just another fresh request caused by `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Comment: did not work .. happens when the post is still going through the controller that makes the list of all
  of the users .. happening in the action seeking a User by the name ... an example
except when a New User and lack algun required field adds to the model error and the model Retron with error messages at this time there is the post in the method of seeking a
User not being sent to look .. and this problem.

Comment: @Borracha sorry but it's really impossible to understand what you are trying to say